# On Capitalism and Communism

Tags: zizek

In an [interview/talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXVEnxtZe_w) Zizek points out that capitalism has received maximum boost in counties with communist ideologies (China) . How can this trend be explained considering both systems have  different objectives and ideas with respect to trade?

Comment: What do you mean by "capitalism has received maximum boost "?

Comment: Is there any chance you could clarify this a bit? What exactly are you hoping for someone to explain to you?

Comment: Also, post Deng Xiaopeng it's not so clear how "communist" China really is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with commenters that question as it stands is unlikely to elicit good answers. Given the lack of context and the wildly spluttering, multi-limbed brain of Zizek, who knows?

I will offer one modest, reasonable reply. To many Marxist theorists, such as Luxemburg and Karatami, Capital accumulation always requires a *noncapitalist* environment, *relatively* unexploited resources and populations external to the system. I believe this is correct.

The most obvious examples are 19th-century imperialism and the modern "liberation" movements that drew minorities, women, "youth vanguards," etc.,  into labor and consumption systems. This noncapitalist environment, or *The Frontier,* can be anything, from a rainforest to public institutions, from the family home to a war zone. And it can be continually recreated, by sheer destruction of Capital if need be.

So from the perspective of Capital, eventual penetration of the billion-plus labor force and consumption capacities of the supposedly communist countries was essential, perhaps inevitable. Why was it reciprocal?

First, no Marxist would describe the Soviet Union or China as communist. With the collapse of the Second International and the failure global revolution, Russia and later China were still-born as deformed, state-capitalist systems regressing into international competition with the liberal capitalist nation states.

Since the states failed dramatically to "wither away" they remained precariously "on top" with all the modern state problems of stabilizing and appeasing mass populations increasingly alienated from "the revolution." They could not help but observe that "consumerism" proved to be an unsurpassable tool of regulation, political diversion, and popular quiescence. What else were they to do?

Marxism proper is, like Christianity, a "universalist" ideology and "utopian" aspiration. When the social structure remains locked into "state" structures policies are determined of necessity by the other, antagonistic states, not by some aspirational ideology. As "states" organizing "capital," the "different objectives" you cite are entirely superficial.

For the real answer, you'll have to ask Zizek, in whom a thousand answers bloom.

Answer (score 0):

China has a long civilisation history as a regional hegemon, administered by an imperial bureaucracy; though occasionally wracked by periodic turmoil - sometimes lasting decades.

Given this, one might suppose its lengthy dissolution through the 20C and it's recent reassertion is no more than one of its periodic purging of its state administrative apparatus and then it's slow reconstruction - though to outside eyes, rapid.